# Menu in Ionic 3 - dynamic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Currently 2 windows, my login, and my home, my menu is in app.html, in this menu, I have the user's name an interpolation `{{user}}`.

But this user is loaded when he enters the login, that is to say, that when he just logs me in, he brings me the name and interpolates it, I do not know how to achieve that if I can help

> For example, this interpolation gives Ivan value, when it is in the
>   home, but does not reflect the changes in the menu

**app.html**:

```
<ion-menu [content]="mycontent">
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <p>{{ usuario }}</p>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
<ion-nav #mycontent [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

**home.html**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  usuario: string = "Ivan"
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public menuCtrl: MenuController) {
    this.menuCtrl.enable(true);
  }     
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you are putting this code:

```
<ion-menu [content]="mycontent">
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <p>{{ usuario }}</p>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
```

in the wrong file. Put it in `home.html`. The way `ionic` works is, when you load `home.html` by going to your `home` page, the app loads the `home` page in `rootPage` in `app.html`. You don't actually put any code in `app.html`.